# Having trouble getting position on the 2nd Array

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm Using GSON to parse my JSON. I have an object that has 2 array object. I'm having a problem on getting the TransactionDetails position.

I have a recyclerView that populates the "Transactions" and then when I tap on that it should open the "TransactionDetails". But I'm having trouble on getting the position on TransactionDetails what array to read.

As you can see on the code I need to put a position on [0] because it only loads the 1st array on transaction details.

[JSON Url](https://api.myjson.com/bins/1424ph)

**DetailedTransactionAdapter**

```
class DetailedTransactionAdapter(val transactionFeed: TransactionFeed) :  RecyclerView.Adapter<DetailCustomViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DetailCustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val tr = transactionFeed.Transactions[1].TransactionDetails[position]

  holder.view.txt_programType.text = transactionDetail.ProgramType
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DetailCustomViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_detailed_transaction, parent, false)
        return DetailCustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
         return transactionFeed.Transactions[0].TransactionDetails.count()
    }

}

class DetailCustomViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    init{

    }
}
```

```
class TransactionFeed(val Transactions: List<Transactions>)

class Transactions(val TransactionCode: String,
                   val ProgramID: Int,
                   val ProgramName: String,
                   val ProgramType: String,
                   val ProgramDescription: String,
                   val TransactionID: Int,
                   val UserID: String,
                   val TransactionAmount: Int,
                   val TransactionDate: String,
                   val TransactionDetails: List<TransactionDetails>)

class TransactionDetails(val Clamied: Boolean,
                         val NextToClaim: Boolean,
                         val ProgramDetailID: Int,
                         val TransactionDetailID: Int,
                         val ProgramDetails: String,
                         val ProgramType: String,
                         val TransactionDetailAmount: Int,
                         val TransactionDetailMonth: String)
```

**TransactionsAdapter**

```
lass TransactionsAdapter(val transactionFeed: TransactionFeed) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val tr = transactionFeed.Transactions.get(position)

        holder.view.txt_transaction_id.text = tr.TransactionID.toString()
        holder.view.txt_transaction_date.text = tr.TransactionDate
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_transaction, parent, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return transactionFeed.Transactions.count()
    }
}

class CustomViewHolder(val view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    init{
        view.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(view.context, DetailedTransactionActivity::class.java)
            view.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is rather unclear. Are you asking how to pass the selected position from the `Transactions` `RecyclerView` to the `TransactionDetails` one?

Comment: Kindly post code entire RecyclerView.Adapter.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, When I Transactions (RecyclerView) it intents to the ```TransactionsDetails(that has a recyclerView also)``` My problem is getting which selected position on the ```Transactions RecyclerView``` to load the right ```TransactionsDetails```

Comment: Well, assuming both `Adapter`s are using the same `TransactionFeed`, you could simply pass the position from the first `Adapter` on the `Intent`; e.g., `intent.putExtra("position", getAdapterPosition())`. Then, `intent.getIntExtra("position", -1)`, in the next `Activity`, and give that to the `Adapter` there (if it's not the default value of `-1`, anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to set appropriate position in getItemCount() and onBindViewHolder() of DetailedTransactionAdapter. Here is how you can go about doing it:

First pass selected transaction position in TransactionsAdapter (when user clicks on any transaction) via intent to DetailedTransactionActivity.

```
class CustomViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    init {
        view.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(view.context, DetailedTransactionActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("selectedTransaction", adapterPosition)
            view.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Then get that position in DetailedTransactionActivity and pass it to DetailedTransactionAdapter.

```
    val transactionPos = intent.getIntExtra("selectedTransaction", -1)
    detailedTransactionAdapter = DetailedTransactionAdapter(transactionFeed, transactionPos)
```

You'll have to change your DetailedTransactionAdapter to also have selectedTransaction as a field. This will help in dynamically populating adapter and binding appropriate data to view. Change adapter impl to this:

```
    class DetailedTransactionAdapter(val transactionFeed: TransactionFeed, val selectedTransaction:Int) :  RecyclerView.Adapter<DetailCustomViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DetailCustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if(selectedTransaction == -1){
            return
        }

        val tr = transactionFeed.Transactions[selectedTransaction].TransactionDetails[position]

        holder.view.txt_programType.text = transactionDetail.ProgramType
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DetailCustomViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_detailed_transaction, parent, false)
        return DetailCustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return transactionFeed.Transactions[selectedTransaction].TransactionDetails.count()
    }
}
```

This is where magic happens. You are returning appropriate transaction details count

> return transactionFeed.Transactions[selectedTransaction].TransactionDetails.count()

and binding data.

> val tr = transactionFeed.Transactions[selectedTransaction].TransactionDetails[position]

So when you have selected first transaction, this will return count of transaction details of **transaction[0]** which is first transaction. And when any other transaction is selected, this will return its transaction details and populate adapter with its data.